# proxy::dist - R 3.6.3 and R 4.0.3 return different results. Why?

Tags: r, proxy

I found a strange behavior with the `proxy::dist` function. In R **3.6.3** I get:

```
options(digits = 22)
a <- c(-0.10349258253435502, 0.01671254492592697)
b <- c(1.1047184643483571e-26, 0.0000000000000000e+00)
as.vector(1 - proxy::dist(t(a), t(b), method = 'cosine'))
0.98721082297543328
```

but in R **4.0.3** I get:

```
-0.98721082297543328 (with a minus sign)
```

In my task I calculate the **cosine similarity** between two vectors and the correct values that I can get are from 0 to 90 degrees. So it seems to me that something is wrong with `proxy::dist` in R **4.0.3**.

The above two results converted to degrees:

```
rad2deg <- function(rad) {(rad * 180) / (pi)}

> rad2deg(acos(0.98721082297543328))
[1] 9.1732424999628215

> rad2deg(acos(-0.98721082297543328))
[1] 170.82675750003719
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of the proxy package with both version?

Comment: in R 3.6.3 it is 0.4-25, 
in R 4.0.3 it is 0.4-26

Comment: From the version history from the Proxy package rev 0.4-26: "Change coercion function for cosine similarity to distance to 1-x instead of 1-abs(x)"

Comment: That's the point! Thank you!